# language reference for current command being executed

Tags: jq

I was just wondering if there is a way to reference the query we are doing?

```
jq { "foo": currentquerystring }
```

this jq command would output:

```
{ "foo": "{ \"foo\": currentquerystring }" }
```

I realize the input can come from include files, is there some way I can get a look at the string that jq parses? Is there such a reference for *currentquerystring* ?

Comment: I don't think there is. What do you need that for though?

Comment: i wanted to annotate my jq output. a meta data pedigree of sorts.

Answer (score 1):

> the string that jq parses

If you use the -n command-line option, then the JSON that jq is currently parsing is none other than `input`; otherwise, it is `.`.

So you could for example write:

```
jq '. as $json | ....'
```

where .... can contain `$json`.

You might also like to look at the documentation for `input_filename` and `input_filename` for finer-grain details about the JSON being read.

(`$__loc__` by contrast gives some information about where in the jq program execution is taking place.)

Comment: the input_filename and input_line_number are useful metadata. ty.

Comment: In practice, `debug` is frequently helpful.